# My Server Laravel Cron Schedule doesn't work

Tags: php, laravel, cron

I tried this for days and seeking answers but it still not working

```
* * * * * usr/bin/php /home/dss/laravelAppDss/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

[image]

Here is my Kernel.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Console;

use Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel as ConsoleKernel;

class Kernel extends ConsoleKernel
{
    protected $commands = [
        '\App\Console\Commands\SinkronDSS',
    ];

    protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
    {
        $schedule->command('sinkron:dss')->daily()->timezone('Asia/Singapore');
    }

    protected function commands()
    {
        require base_path('routes/console.php');
    }
}
```

Here is my SinkronDSS.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Console\Commands;

use Illuminate\Console\Command;

class SinkronDSS extends Command
{
    protected $signature = 'sinkron:dss';

    protected $description = 'Sinkron DSS';

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function handle()
    {
        $sync = app('\App\Http\Controllers\SinkronisasiC')->db_pdd(true);
        $sync = app('\App\Http\Controllers\SinkronisasiC')->db_pdm(true);
        $sync = app('\App\Http\Controllers\SinkronisasiC')->db_pdp(true);
        $sync = app('\App\Http\Controllers\SinkronisasiC')->db_remun(true);
        $sync = app('\App\Http\Controllers\SinkronisasiC')->db_kinerja(true);
    }
}
```

I tried php artisan schedule:run in local and it's working fine...

Anyone know where is the problem?

Comment: Sorry for not being able to help you with the `cron`, but I just saw you are "scheduling" controllers ? What are you doing there ? That is really bad, don't ever `app` or `resolve` controllers... you have to run `job`s or `command`s to sync, not controllers...

Comment: try to use "/usr/local/bin/php"  instead of  "usr/bin/php"

Comment: @matiaslauriti I do use command on the Kernel.php, the command call all those Controllers, it do works fine in local

Comment: @huzaifaqidwai yeah I'll try this, I think that's the problem

Comment: @AdityaPratama I mean, do what you want, but if you work in a place and you `app` or `resolve` a controller **ANYWHERE** and I am the one evaluating your code-test to enter a company, I would directly say no to you. I am just trying to give you a tip from my seniority...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry that I do not have enough reputations to leave comment so I need to write as an answer....

If you can run `php artisan schedule:run`, I would suggest it seems that the cronjob is not running with the correct path to `php`.

1. Have you tried `usr/bin/php /home/dss/laravelAppDss/artisan schedule:run`?
2. Have you tried to add `/` before `user/bin/php`?
   i.e.:
   `* * * * * /usr/bin/php /home/dss/laravelAppDss/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1`

Comment: I've tried 1 but I'll try 2, I think that's the answer

Comment: @AdityaPratama Great!

Comment: @matiaslauriti Although it is off topic, may I ask what do you mean for "not to `app` or `resolve` a controller ANYWhHERE"? Is that meant not to use "app('\App\Http\Controllers\SinkronisasiC')" in code but creating Controller object and call the functions? I am very interested in your tip. Thank you.

Comment: Not having enough rep does not give you permission to post comments here in the answer section. Normally I would request you delete this but, fortunately, the question asker has determined your post answers his question. [answer]